# epstopdf : "No appropriate script or program found: epstopdf"

Tags: errors, miktex, epstopdf, protext

I have a paper I am trying to submit to a journal, but my advisor is unable to get it to compile on his computer.  He has Windows XP.

It compiles on my Mac, and I also compiled it on Windows Vista (downloaded [`ProTeXt`](http://www.tug.org/protext/), which includes MiKTeX 2.9, as well as the `IEEEtran.sty` file since it wasn't included) and it worked on Vista,

but when we try it on XP, we get a `No appropriate script or program found: epstopdf` for the epstopdf script.  I don't understand; it is the exact same installation of `ProTeXt` that I used.  Googling reveals that it may have something to do with security or script execution?

We'd love to use LaTeX but we're thinking about going back to Word. It works much better and doesn't have all these weird problems :P

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You may have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436).

Comment: verify `epstopdf -v` is installed at commandline, then run `pdflatex --enable-write18` 
by adding `\usepackage{epstopdf}` to preamble to automatically convert `.eps` figures to `.pdf`. Remember `\write18` is enabled by `--enable-write18` flag.
 .

Comment: Please see this related thread at latex-community [pdfcrop: The Perl script could not be found](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=14677) if it may help. you may need [perl installation](http://www.activestate.com/activeperl/downloads) to make pdfcrop work for a MiKTeX distro

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try the "eps2pdf" command such as the one given [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/5782-eps2pdf), it might help.